# Obtain predicted class from output array of probabilities

Tags: python, numpy

I did the function that gets the max probability between the classes but I am asking if there a builtin function that does this, am afraid if my function contains bugs.

```
y_pred_formed=[]
y_pred=model.predict(features)
print(y_pred.shape)
for i in range(y_pred.shape[0]):
    maximum = np.argmax(y_pred[i])
    y_pred_formed.append(maximum)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) takes an `axis` parameter, so you could simplify the above to:

```
y_pred = np.array([[0.3, 0.4, 0.3], [0.8, 0.2, 0.], [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]]) #example array

print(y_pred)
array([[0.3, 0.4, 0.3],
       [0.8, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]])

y_pred.argmax(axis=1)
# array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```